# Kendo grid header or title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I look at this [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) and there is a header on the grid named "Customer Database". What tag do I need to use to add this title within the `*.cshtml` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but if you're asking how you can set that header on the grid in the .cshtml file, it's a background image, applied via CSS. You can see it [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/content/web/grid/clientsDb.png).

Comment: I don't know for what is this minus exactly but ok. Thanks I what to know this

Comment: Your question was hard to understand but I'm glad that's answered it for you.